# Why can't I downvote answers or questions?

Tags: support, voting, privileges

When I first created my account, I tried to vote on an answer. But it said that I must have 15 reputation to vote.

After some time, I got up to 21 reputation, and I voted on an answer I liked. But when I tried to vote on another one, it said I must have 125 reputation!

What is happening?

Edit: I've noticed that I can upvote, but not downvote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how the site is designed.

Upvoting and downvoting are some of the many [privileges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) that are unlocked that require 15 and 125 reputation respectively. Downvoting will lower users reputation, so you need to be more established in the site before unlocking this privilege.

Comment: Additionally, downvoting on an answer will lower **your** reputation as well.